# Cannot fix BindException -- cannot figure out/understand if threads are using new ports to connect to server instead of reusing the same port?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm new to load testing, HTTP requests, using ports, and JMeter (version 5.5).

I'm trying to do a load test for 100 concurrent users and keep running into the "BindException - address already in use" error, as well as "SocketException - socket closed" error for the first time just now. I've used the [baselogic link](https://www.baselogic.com/2011/11/23/solved-java-net-bindexception-address-use-connect-issue-windows/) I've seen around here to configure the MaxUserPort and TcpTimedWaitDelay values to 65534 and 30, respectively. It seems that the ports being used to send samples/requests is the issue, because before I set MaxUserPort, I could only send up to ~16,000 samples every test run while now the test will always run to ~64,000 samples before quitting (set the test to stop after an error). Setting the MaxUserPort to 32768 also only allowed around ~31,000 samples before an error, which is why I feel like my problem is related to ports.

So, I'm wondering if the 100 threads/users I'm trying to run use more than 1 port when sending samples? From my understanding, if my HTTP request has "keep-alive" checked and "HttpClient4" selected (in the advanced tab), then the maximum number of ports used should be 100 once the ramp-up time is reached, no? Because right now it seems that that must not be the case and that threads are using new ports to send new requests?

For reference, I am using a 16gb ram computer. I've put all of my listeners and unneeded assertions in another controller and disabled the controller, and tried disabling all of them in it as well to see if that changes anything. The concurrency thread group has target concurrency: 100, ramp up time: 200 sec, ramp up steps: 0, hold target rate: 15 sec, thread iterations limit: -1. The application I'm sending HTTP POST requests to is also run on localhost, so JMeter and the app are running on the same computer (currently no options for distributed testing/using 2 different computers). I've run this test via GUI and non-GUI and get a BindException error around the same number of samples either way, which hits around 45 sec - 1 min.

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

64000 "samples" more or less equal to the number of possible ports in your system

You've increased the dynamic port range but did nothing with this bit:

> and takes up to 4 minutes to recycle them

so my expectation is that you also need to amend the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\TcpTimedWaitDelay` to be closer to the time it takes for 1 iteration of your test.

Another possible workaround is setting iterations limit to 1, this way 1 thread (virtual user) will establish connection once taking only one port and re-use this connection on subsequent iterations

In general running the load generator and the system under test on the same machine is not a very good idea due to possible [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), both can become very resource intensive and will be stealing each others memory pages and CPU cycles so you will be getting false-negative results.

Moreover you won't be able to measure resources consumption and correlate it with the increasing load using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)

Even if you deploy JMeter and the system under test onto different machines but the system under test won't run on production-like environment - there are not too many things you can test in a scaled down environment as you cannot extrapolate the results. Of course you can do some [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) or checking for [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) but any attempts to measure response times or throughput won
t give you any value because they will be different on another machine.